# How do I modify the width of a TextCtrl in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to create a text control that has the default height but a custom width. This is my current code:

```
tc = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1)
tc.Size.SetWidth(300)
```

The width of the text control remains unchanged though. I've also tried calling `tc.Layout()` after changing the width with no results. I don't want to have to input a custom size in the class constructor since I want it to use the default height. I have also tried being more verbose, in case `tc.GetSize` returns a deep copy of the `Size` object:

```
tc = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(300, 23))

tc_size = tc.Size
tc_size.SetWidth(300)

tc.Size = tc_size
tc.Layout()
```

Also to no avail. Why is my code not working, and how do I make it work?

---

<sup>Setting the size in the constructor works, so the sizer is irrelevant to the problem.</sup>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just noticed that I can pass `(300, -1)` as the size of the text control:

```
wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(300, -1))
```

Which results in the text control using the default height. This solves my problem but doesn't technically answer my question, so I'm holding out for a better answer.

---

Edit: This answer plus the below comments answers my question.

Comment: @tom10: My question is about modifying the width of a text control, not passing the size in the constructor.

Comment: What happens with txt.SetSize((300,-1))?

Comment: @PaulMcNett: Nothing. The text control remains at its default size.

Comment: Because setting the since in the constructor also sets the min size, and it is the min size that sizers give priority to.  If you are using a sizer and want to change the size to an explicit size then the easiest thing to do is use SetMinSize followed by a sizer.Layout()

Comment: @RobinDunn: Is the same true for maximum size? Say I want to stop a sizer from increasing the height of my text controls? Also, thanks for the comment Mr. wxPython :)

Comment: I think that code for honoring the max size of items in sizers has recently been added for 2.9.5

Answer (score 4):

You should let sizers control the size of your controls, not set them explicitly.

```
import wx

class Frm(wx.Frame):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(Frm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      txt = wx.TextCtrl(self)
      s = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
      s.Add(txt, 1)
      self.SetSizer(s)
      self.Layout()


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = Frm(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

This lets controls lay themselves out relative to one another with general guidance from your code. So running the same code on Mac versus Windows, for example, should still result in a nice layout.

I realize this doesn't directly answer your question, but wanted to nudge you to sizers in case you weren't aware of them. It takes a lot of the drudgery out of writing and maintaining your UI layout.

Comment: +1 I am using sizers for layout, but I have a specific width I want for my text controls and I want the dialog to be as large as the controls require, not the other way around. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: In that case you do want to set the width explicitly but leave the height as default, and the way I know to do that is your original finding (SetSize((desired_width, -1))).

Comment: But my question demonstrates that `SetSize` has no effect on the size